# How to find $\lim_{x\to +\infty}{\left(\sqrt{\pi}x-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+2}}{2n!(2n+1)(2n+2)}\right)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}{\left(\sqrt{\pi}x-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+2}}{2n!(2n+1)(2n+2)}\right)}$$

This limit comes from the following integral, which I expand it into Taylor series.
$$S=2\int_0^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt\right)dx$$

My attempt is to solve the integral $S$, but I can't find a proper way, so I expand it into Taylor series and the question I ask is where I stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.** You may just integrate your initial integral by parts,
$$
\begin{align}S&=2\int_0^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt\right)dx\\
&=2\left[x\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt\right)\right]_0^\infty+\underbrace{2\int_0^{+\infty}xe^{-x^2}dx}_{u=x^2\,\,du=2xdx}\\
&=0+\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-u}du\\
&=1.
\end{align}
$$ The desired limit is then equal to $1$.

Observe that we have used the [classic gaussian integral result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral),

> $$
> \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
> $$

to obtain, as $x \to +\infty$,
$$
\left|x\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt\right)\right|=\left|x\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}dt\right|\leq \left|x\int_x^\infty e^{-xt}dt\right|=e^{-x^2}\to 0.
$$

Comment: Yes ,just integral by parts is so much easier. I take a stupid way to do it in the beginning. And can I expand $e^{-t^2}$ into Taylor series and do the calculation.(Just theoretically, I do not expect the limits to be solved)

Comment: @Rowan Yes, you are allowed to expand $e^{-t^2}$ into its Taylor series since the radius of convergence is infinite. Thanks!